# Two 3-way switches, two separate lights, one circuit

Tags: stairs

I was having issues with old wiring in my stairway and discovered that the circuit they were on was overloaded.  The wiring was old and not grounded, the gang boxes were loose, etc...  I replaced the wiring and am pulling power from a separate circuit.  The old circuit came from the attic and now the new one comes from the basement.  That's where I got lost with rewiring things.

As you'll see in the picture, it's just a light at the top of the stairs and a light at the bottom.  Each has its own 3-way switch.  Power is coming into the bottom box now.

Anyone mind adding to my MSPaint drawing with recommended wiring setup?  I'm good on grounds.

[image: stairsetup]

Comment: Does the 12/2 exiting the upstairs light bring constant power in from the old attic circuit, or is it feeding power or a switched-hot out to other loads?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, those two 12/2 lines exiting each light just go to their respective switches.  They don't power anything else.  I was just showing that they have been re-wired using 12/2 to the switches.

Comment: so you want to switch the two lights independantly?

Comment: That's correct.  Switches on right side of both operate bottom light.  Switches on left side of both operate top light.

Comment: @Jasen We don't know if they are pendant lights or not. We know they are independ**e**nt. :-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is all based on the assumption that because you are rebuilding what already exists that you are *not* required to have neutral in each switch box. That is a requirement, generally speaking, in new construction with recent versions of the NEC. I am not 100% certain it requires "neutral in *every* switch box of a 3-way circuit" but it might. But assuming that's not an issue, the following should work. Note that I am using a color-scheme from various other Harper (and other) posts:

- Black = hot
- White = neutral (this is an NEC requirement)
- Red = switched hot
- Yellow = travelers

##### Downstairs light/right switches

- Neutral from panel white to light white (pigtailed with upstairs /3 white)
- Hot from panel black to /3 white (pigtailed with bottom left black screw). *Mark the /3 white with black tape on both ends to indicate it is hot and not neutral.*
- Red and black of /3 to brass screws of top and bottom switches. *Mark the red and black wires with yellow tape on both ends to indicate they are travelers and not hot or switched hot.*
- Top switch black screw to /3 white
- Bottom switch black screw to light black. *Mark this black wire with red tape.*

##### Upstairs light/left switches

- Neutral from panel white to /3 white
- Hot from panel black to bottom switch black screw
- Neutral from /3 white to light white
- Black and red of /3 to brass screws of top and bottom switches. *Mark the black and red wires with yellow tape on both ends to indicate they are travelers and not hot or switched hot.*
- Top switch black screw to light black. *Mark this black wire with red tape.*

Because of "neutral is always white even though white is not always neutral", I don't see any alternatives for the upstairs light. Must send neutral up unswitched, therefore white is neutral and black and red are travelers. On the other hand, the downstairs light has a few different possibilities, including sending hot up unswitched and travelers down vs. sending travelers up and switched hot down.

Note also that if you ever do want to install smart switches, you can do so as long as you put the "main" parts in the bottom box, as you have neutral for *both* lights in that box.

With this scheme (or any equivalent but marked the same), you will be able to look at the wires on any of the switches and immediately know which wires are hot (black), neutral (white), travelers (yellow) or switched hot (red). The only thing that will not be obvious is upstairs/left vs. downstairs/right. For the sanity of those using the switches and any future people working on the circuits, definitely stick with left=upstairs light, right=downstairs light (or vice versa) and not top left/bottom right = upstairs and top right/bottom left = downstairs.

Comment: code says where possible marked white should be always hot - use red-black for travelers.

Comment: @Jasen I know that's the case for a /2 switch loop, not sure for a /3 travelers situation, but I'll redo based on that.

Comment: Thank you both!

Comment: Just wanted to follow-up and say that this worked perfectly!  Thank you again.